# invalidate() control inside tableLayoutpanel does not fire paint event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added controls inside table layout panel and I invalidated (Invalidate()) the controls inside, but it does not fire the paint events.
below shows my code snippet. I tried to use the Update() method as well as refresh() methods, but still does not fire the paint event,

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        private ShadowMode _shadowStyle = ShadowMode.ForwardDiagonal;
        [Browsable(true), Category("MyPanel"), Description("Style of the shadow.")]
        public ShadowMode ShadowStyle
        {
            get
            {
                return _shadowStyle;
            }
            set
            {
                _shadowStyle = value;
                Invalidate();
                Update();
                Refresh();
            }
        }
        public MyPanel()
        {
            this.Paint += this.AdvancedPanel_Paint;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        }
```

and implemented the paint event as below.

private void AdvancedPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
}

and I added the myPanel control inside a table layoutPanel and set the ShadowStyle and expected to execute the above paint event, but it does not fire the paint event.

But If I add a my panel control directly on the form itself, and modify the ShadowStyle, then it fires the paint event.

Can anybody let me know why the paint event does not fire inside table layout panel?

Thank you

Below shows the full source code

Create WInforms Application.
Inside the pragram.cs main method

```
 Application.Run(new Form4());
```

## the Form4

```
partial class Form4
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.myPanel1 = new WindowsFormsApp1.MyPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.myPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.myPanel1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // myPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.myPanel1, 2);
            this.myPanel1.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel2);
            this.myPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.myPanel1.EdgeWidth = 2;
            this.myPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.myPanel1.Name = "myPanel1";
            this.myPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(794, 219);
            this.myPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel2
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(794, 219);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form4
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Name = "Form4";
            this.Text = "Form4";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.myPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private MyPanel myPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel2;
    }
```

===========================================

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myPanel1.EdgeWidth = 1;
        }
    }
```

=======================================================

```
 public class MyPanel : Panel
        {
    
    
            private int _edgeWidth = 2;
            /// <summary>
            /// The width of an edge
            /// </summary>
            [Browsable(true), Category("MyPanel"), Description("The width of an edge.")]
            public int EdgeWidth
            {
                get
                {
                    return _edgeWidth;
                }
                set
                {
                    _edgeWidth = value;
                     Invalidate();
                    
                }
            }
            public MyPanel()
            {
                //this.Size = new Size(200, 50);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                //SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
                //SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                //SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            }

    

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

I added a break point to OnPaint methods to check whether the method is fired. when the application runs it does not hit the break point. But if I removed the myPanel() constructor codes, then it hits the break point.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, please add all appropriate tags, e.g. questions specific to Windows Forms should be tagged so.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. We can't copy and paste code from a picture to test it for ourselves, which is just one problem. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: If you want to create a custom control that does its own custom painting, you don't handle the `Paint` event. You override the `OnPaint` method. In that method, you call the base method to do all the standard painting. Any drawing you do before that call will be done before the standard painting and any drawing you do after that call will be done after the standard painting.

Comment: I overrride the onpaint event, but thats also not fired when above invalidate() is called. DO I miss anything elese?

Comment: Show us the new code. I have tested a custom `Label` and the `OnPaint` method is invoked when I call `Invalidate` in a property setter.

Comment: I could narrow down the issue further,  mycustom panel  constructor includes the       SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true); and 
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true); and the custom panel will be inside a table layout panel and another table layout panel is included inside the custom panel. all the controlls  dock style to fill, at this time it does not fire the onpait method

Comment: If the Panel is completely filled with another Control, there's nothing to paint (or re-paint, since you have set `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`).

Comment: There was a lot of relevant information here that was left out of the question in its early iterations and possibly even its latest. Note that no one should have to read the comments to understand the question. You have updated the question along the way, so that's good. Just reminding you to update it with all the relevant information, if you haven't already.

Comment: Also note that you really should have done more testing before posting. Your scenario is far more than the "control in a TableLayoutPanel" that you indicated at the start. You should have done as I did and tested with a simple standard control, then a simple custom control, then continued to complicate things one step at a time until it broke. You'll then know exactly where the issue lies and may be able to fix it yourself, but will be able to give us far more relevant information if you still need to post. Do all you can first, then ask the most specific question possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following against .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 and it worked in both cases. Note that I started this test before you provided your code, so it doesn't correlate exactly, but it does demonstrate that things work as you think they should, so the issue is specific to what you're doing, which we're h=yet to see enough of to fully diagnose.

1. Create a new WinForms project.
2. Add the following class:

```cs
public class LabelEx : Label
{
    private Color boxColour = Color.Blue;

    public Color BoxColour
    {
        get
        {
            return boxColour;
        }
        set
        {
            boxColour = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public LabelEx()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (var boxPen = new Pen(boxColour))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(boxPen,
                                     10,
                                     10,
                                     50,
                                     25);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Add a `TableLayoutPanel` to the form.
4. Add a `Label` and a `LabelEx` to the `TableLayoutPanel`, setting `Dock` to `Fill` for both.
5. Add two `Button` controls to the form.
6. Add the following code to the form:

```cs
private Color boxColour = Color.Blue;

private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var boxPen = new Pen(boxColour))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(boxPen,
                                 10,
                                 10,
                                 50,
                                 25);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    boxColour = Color.Red;
    label1.Invalidate();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelEx1.BoxColour = Color.Red;
}
```

7. Attach the methods in the above code to the appropriate events of the appropriate controls.
8. Run the project.
9. Click the `Button` controls.

When you click the `Buttons` you will see the boxes drawn on the `Label` and `LabelEx` change colour, proving that the appropriate methods and events are being invoked.

Comment: The Label has `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` set by default (unless you change its `FlatStyle` to `FlatStyle.System`) -- The OP is docking another Control inside that Panel, completely covering it. So there's nothing to paint (when `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` is set).